# Query table within variable schemanames

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to run a query of a table within variable schemas.

I have a postgresql db that I've written the following query for:

```
SELECT
    project_id, project_name, schema_p
FROM public.projects
JOIN public.schema_ps
ON public.schema_ps.root_id = public.projects.project_id
ORDER BY project_id ASC
```

The `schema_p` column contains the names of schemas that all have a table named `com_set` that I need to query as follows:

```
SELECT dev_id, dev_name FROM [variable_schama_name].com_set
```

What I'd like to do is write a query to generate a single combined result, where my resulting dataset would contain the columns of `project_id`, `project_name`, `schema_p`, `dev_id`, and `dev_name`. This would mean I'd have repeats in the first three columns and unique entries in the second last two columns. One way to think of it is that I'd like to run the first query to get the names of the schemas, then run the second query on each of the schemas.

Hopefully that all makes sense. Thanks for the help!

Comment: how many shema_names do you talk about ?

Comment: At present, about 50, but that will increase over time.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution relies on a dynamic query without guarantee about the performance :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_query(OUT project_id int, OUT project_name text, OUT schema_p text, OUT dev_id int, OUT dev_name text)
RETURNS setof record LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
  txt text ;
BEGIN
SELECT string_agg(
'SELECT p.project_id, p.project_name, s.schema_p, c.dev_id, c.dev_name
  FROM public.projects AS p
  INNER JOIN public.schema_ps AS s
    ON s.root_id = p.project_id
 CROSS JOIN ' || ps.schema_p || '.com_set AS c', ' UNION ALL ')
|| ' ORDER BY project_id ASC'
FROM public.schema_ps AS ps
INTO txt ;

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE txt ;

END ; $$ ;
```

and then you just call `my_query` :

```
SELECT my_query() ;
```

Comment: This almost worked. I get all of the c.dev_id and c.dev_name items, but every one of them shows up in every single schema, which is not correct. As a result, I have about 65,000 results when, at present, there should be only around 1100.